# Is it possible to obtain a work permit for a teaching role in the UK without a teaching degree?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I have a friend who is American, and cannot qualify under any normal visa for the UK.  I heard teaching is in high demand in the UK and it is possible to work as a teacher if the company you are working for applies for a special work permit for you.

My friend is not a qualified teacher (no teaching degree), but she has 6 months experience teaching a class of pre-school students by her self.  If she travelled to England on a tourist visa (6 months) how likely is it she would be able to find a job (pre-school or otherwise) and the company would apply for a work permit for her?

Comment: Is this for charity work or for a paid job? Visa category and rules vary according to that.

Comment: Ideally it would be paid, but she would be more than happy with charity work if it could lead to a work visa in a reasonable amount of time, can you expand more on the rules please? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that immigration is a bit political in the UK at the moment, and cracking down on un-skilled / low skill immigration from outside the EU seems to be the government's preferred way to "look tough" whilst being legal. Expect things to be tougher than they used to be...

Comment: I think this question has a good chance of getting an answer from somebody with direct experience if you as on the Lonely Planet Thorn Tree: http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forum.jspa?forumID=25

Answer (score 4):

There are two categories of visa that could be applicable in this case:

- [**Tier 5 (Charity worker)**](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier5/charityworkers/): This is only for working in charitale organisations. Unlike other Tier 5 visas - which I don't think are applicable in this case - this category [doesn't allow switching to another visa type](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier2/general/eligibility/switching/).
- **[Tier 2 (General)](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier2/general/)**: This category allows for working but it also [requires 'sponsorship' of the visa application](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier2/general/eligibility/pointsassessment/sponsorship/) (basically, an endorsement) by a company that is registered to allow migrant workers. Applications are [assessed according to a points-based system](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/workingintheuk/tier2/general/eligibility/pointsassessment/pointsscore/).

Whether a company sponsors without a teaching degree is up to the company; this should be easier in the case of working in charitable organisations.

Comment: So the company can decide to sponsor without a teaching degree?  I was worried it was against the law or similar to do so?

Comment: I am not away of any documentation on this being illegal, but it will be *very* hard to get a sponsor if there are comparable British candidates. And while there's no specific visa rules on teachers, there may very well be directives / standard practices in teaching institutions not to hire people without a teaching degree. That's outside the scope of Travel.SE of course.